# Triplen harmonics not appearing in the output of DigSilent PowerFactory 2021

Tags: power, harmonics, power-quality

I am running simulations for harmonics resulting from the connection of an offshore wind farm to the main grid on DigSilent PowerFactory 2021 SP3. I am using a script to run multiple scenarios and store the output in CSV files. Based on the design, I know that the triplen harmonics should be suppressed and their magnitude should be zero but I still want them to appear in the output CSV file clearly showing that the magnitude of those harmonics is indeed zero.  I could do it by hand in MS Excel but I am gonna be dealing with hundreds of files and it would be very tedious.

If anyone here has faced the same problem and found the solution, please help me out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the software you mention, but seems to me you could just write a script that inserts the "triplen = 0" data you need to the csv files. Probably low effort to write with Python.

Comment: Have you tried the FFT function?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, folks. I just wrote a small script to batch edit all the files for missing harmonics as Vicente said.